# How to Properly Space SKSpriteNodes?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm working on a game where nodes are continuously scrolling down the screen. I have them set up to spawn at a certain position and everything looks even:

[image: Iphone screen with game playing]

The issue occurs when the user pauses the game repeatedly, the nodes get misaligned like so:

[image: iphone screen with game playing]

I believe that when I pause the game my timing is thrown off. Here are my updateCurrentTime() functions. I have it set so it adds a new random row every 0.6 seconds.

```
 func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate (_ timeSinceLastUpdate:CFTimeInterval) {
    lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
    if lastYieldTimeInterval > 0.6 {
        lastYieldTimeInterval = 0
        addRandomRow()
    }
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if screenIsPaused == 1{
        pauseScreen()
    }else if screenIsPaused == 0{
    unPauseScreen()
        screenIsPaused = 2
    }  else if screenIsPaused == 3{
        gameLayer.isPaused = true
    }

    var timeSinceLastUpdate = currentTime - lastUpdateTimeInterval
    lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime

    if timeSinceLastUpdate > 1 {
        timeSinceLastUpdate = 1/60
        lastUpdateTimeInterval = currentTime
    }
    updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate(timeSinceLastUpdate)
}
```

Here is the code that I use to pause my game:

```
 func pauseScreen(){
    overlay.color = UIColor.black
    overlay.alpha = 0.6
    overlay.size.height = self.size.height
    overlay.size.width = self.size.width
    overlay.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    overlay.zPosition = 100
        addChild(overlay)
gameLayer.isPaused = true
  screenIsPaused = 3

    label.text = "Press screen to play!"
    label.fontColor = SKColor.white
    label.fontSize = 50
    label.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width / 2, y: self.size.height / 2)
    addChild(label)
   let Fade = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: 1), SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 1)])
    label.run(SKAction.repeatForever(Fade))
}

func unPauseScreen(){
   label.removeFromParent()
   overlay.removeFromParent()
    screenIsPaused = 2
```

`gameLayer.isPaused = false
    }`

The pause function is called in touchesEnded() and the un-pause function is called in touchesBegan.

Please let me know if there is anything I can try or if you require more information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I'm not sure if it is the best answer; however, it works. I modified my function `updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate` here it is now:

```
func updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate (_ timeSinceLastUpdate:CFTimeInterval) {
    if lastYieldTimeInterval > 0.6 {

        lastYieldTimeInterval = 0
        addRandomRow()
    }

        if screenIsPaused == 1{
            pauseScreen()
            lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
        }else if screenIsPaused == 0{
            unPauseScreen()
            lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
            screenIsPaused = 2
        }  else if screenIsPaused == 3{
            gameLayer.isPaused = true
        }else if screenIsPaused == 2{
            lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate
        }
}
```

I moved that screenIsPaused if statements here instead of my `update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)`. In addition, I added `lastYieldTimeInterval += timeSinceLastUpdate` into each of the if statements. Now every time the game pauses or un-pauses the time is updated.